# Psycopg2 not commiting changes

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='%s' user='%s' host='%s' password='%s' port='%s'" % (db, user, server, password, port))
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("UPDATE bazos_ads SET price = replace(price, 'Zadarmo', '-5')")
cursor.execute("UPDATE bazos_ads SET price = replace(price, 'Nerozhoduje', '-4')")
cursor.execute("UPDATE bazos_ads SET price = replace(price, 'Ponúknite', '-3')")
cursor.execute("UPDATE bazos_ads SET price = replace(price, 'Dohodou', '-2')")
cursor.execute("UPDATE bazos_ads SET price = replace(price, 'V texte', '-1')")
cursor.execute("UPDATE bazos_ads SET price = replace(price, '€', '')")
cursor.execute("UPDATE bazos_ads SET price = replace(price, ' ', '')")

cursor.execute("TRUNCATE infinity_ads")
conn.commit()

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO infinity_ads (site,category,link,number,image,title,info,price,date,locality) SELECT site,category,link,number::integer,image,title,info,price::integer,date::date,locality FROM bazos_ads')
cursor.execute("TRUNCATE bazos_ads")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I need to modify columns in database with TextFields so I am able to copy them into second database with specified column types (Integrer in this case). If I copy those SQLs and run them one-by-one in PSQL it works just fine. But if I try to run this code in python I get this error messagge:

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "6€"
```

So I guess psycopg2 is not commiting changes or there is another problem with replacing € symbol, but I can not figure it out because in PSQL it works OK.

EDIT: I still cant find solution but at least this work:

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -U name-d pass-c "UPDATE bazos_ads SET price = replace(price, 'Zadarmo', '-5')"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "6€"
```

In this case your data is evidently not an integer so `psycopg2` cannot store € into a `Integer` column. If you replace a string with an integer, then you can store the result in an Integer column, otherwise the result of the `replace` function is not an integer thus it throws error at the time of storing the value.

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -U name-d pass-c "UPDATE bazos_ads SET price = replace(price, 'Zadarmo', '-5')"
```

This works because you replace a string with `-5` that is an Integer for Postgre typing and can be properly stored in the target column.